# Save image in DB using .net core webapi

Tags: mysql, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I want to upload a file and save it into MYSQL DB using .net core webapi.
I have googled many times but I am not getting a proper search for that.

Comment: What did you try? Show us your code which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not saving files in any database, save the path of a file if you want but not the file itself.

Files are best stored using the file system, specially if they are large or they will be updated often (blob fragmentation becomes an issue in regards to performance).

I optimised queries from a database with pictures that went from 25GB to 50MB just for saving the images in the file system and the query performance was impressive after that change.

For me, the best way to store files in a database is save the file path if necessary but not the files itself.